# How to set trusted proxies for nextcloud behind nginx proxy manager

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I’m trying to set up a nextcloud docker using nginx proxy manager.
Nextcloud itself works as expected but when I’m looking into the settings under Administration > Overview it says:

> You are accessing your instance over a secure connection, however your
> instance is generating insecure URLs. This most likely means that you
> are behind a reverse proxy and the overwrite config variables are not
> set correctly. Please read the documentation page about this
> :arrow_upper_right:.

As far as I understand I have to add my proxy to trusted proxies either through a environment variable in my docker-compose file or directly in the config.php file but I wasn't able to get it working.

Should I enter a IP or the name of the proxy container? (Apparently the IP changes)
How do I find out which IP I have to use?
Does the environmental variable also support names or just IP address?
Can I use the container name even though the proxy manager is in a separate docker-compose file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use occ tool to set trusted proxies for example:

```
nextcloud-occ config:app:set trusted_proxies 192.168.1.12
```

Where 192.168.1.12 is the ip of your nginx proxy manager

However, to fix this particular error "**your instance is generating insecure URLs**." I had to set **system.verwriteProtocol = "https"**.